# Find the value of $a$ from the equation

Tags: roots

The roots of the equation: $ax^2-(5a+2)x+9a=0$ are equal.

Find the value of $a$ given that $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint #$1$:

$$\frac{(5a+2)\color{red}{+}\sqrt{(5a+2)^2-4a\cdot9a}}{2a}=\frac{(5a+2)\color{red}{-}\sqrt{(5a+2)^2-4a\cdot9a}}{2a}$$

---

Hint #$2$:

$$\color{red}{+}\sqrt{n}=\color{red}{-}\sqrt{n}\implies{n}=0$$

Comment: I would use b^2-4ac, then factorise to solve a

Comment: @Harry: In order for the roots to be equal, indeed $b^2-4ac$ has to be $0$.

Comment: but when i do b^2-4ac, the value is -61a^2-20a-4. this cant be factorized.

Comment: @Harry: How did you get to $-61a^2-20a-4$?????

Comment: @Harry: You have some kind of sign error in your calculations. What you have is $-B^2-4AC$,you should have $B^2-AC$.

Comment: I dont know, how do i get the value of a

Comment: @Harry: Do you understand the hints? If no, what part don't you understand? If yes, what exactly are you having a problem with while using them in order to find the answer? I can't get any more clear than what I've already written (besides explicitly writing the answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal quadratic equation in $x$. How do solve those? Is there some point in solving those where you have a test that tells you how many solutions it has? (The roots being equal is equivalent to it having only one solution).

Comment: I would use b^2-4ac, then factorise to solve a

Answer (score 0):

The *discriminant* of a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is the quantity $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$.  The roots of the quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ are given by the Quadratic Formula
$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$
Observe that the two roots are equal if and only if $\Delta = 0$.

For the quadratic equation $ax^2 - (5a + 2)x + 9a = 0$, with $a > 0$, the discriminant is 
$$\Delta = [-(5a + 2)]^2 - 4a(9a)$$
Set the discriminant equal to zero, solve for $a$, and select the positive solution for $a$.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Could you help solve this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179506/finding-the-formula-for-a-parabola-and-its-derivative-graph