# Finding the formula for a parabola and its antiderivative graph.

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

For part a) i have : $f'(x)= 3x^2-18x+15$

Can someone provide a  straightforward, simple explanation for part b)? Best if no hints are given just an answer with the explanation please.

[image]

Comment: Your solution to part (a) is correct.  Since you know $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 18x + 15$, you must find the function $f(x)$ whose derivative is $f'(x)$ such that $f(0) = 15$.  Compare Bernard's answer with Bye_World's hints, then see if you can work out the details.  I suspect the reason for the downvotes is that you asked for an answer without showing your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x^3-9x^2+15x+15$. An antiderivative of $3x^2 -18x +15$ is $x^3-9x^2+15x+{}$constant, and the constant is the $y$-intercept of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the the derivative of your parabola -- you want the *antiderivative*.

Just think to yourself "What could I take the derivative of to get $3x^2$?  What about $-18x$?  And what about $15$?"

Then once you've figured that out, you just need to add a constant $C$ to your answer, because the derivative of a constant would be zero.  Then knowing that your graph goes through the point $(0,15)$, solve for $C$.